# Create Table in Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is there's a way to create a Table inside Azure Storage Account using ARM template? I can achieve that using PowerShell but can't find a way to do it using JSON template, also when I browse my deployment resources using (https://resources.azure.com) I can't see any reference to the created table under the storage account, any idea why?

Thanks,
A Seyam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As far as I know, no. You could look at [Get started with Azure Table storage using .NET/PHP/Python/...](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) for details.
2. The Table service exposes Account, Tables, Entity via the REST API, so you couldn't see them in the portal. You can check out [Addressing Table Service Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179360.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Steven is correct re: #1 - you cannot do data plane operations for storage in a template deployment. (i.e. can't create queues, containers, tables, etc)

Comment: Actually you can create a container. I haven't found a way to create a storage table yet. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-storage-blob-container/azuredeploy.json

Comment: This answer is outdated. **It is now possible to create tables with both ARM templates and Bicep.** See Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables@2021-06-01

Answer (score 4):

You can create an Azure Storage account with a table via ARM like this, using a `tableServices/tables` sub-resource on your `storageAccount` resource:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3,
      "maxLength": 24
    },
    "storageAccountSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS"
      ]
    },
    "tableName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3,
      "maxLength": 63
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountSku')]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat('default/', parameters('tableName'))]",
          "type": "tableServices/tables",
          "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The functionality is documented on the [ARM Template spec page for tableServices/tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-06-01/storageaccounts/tableservices/tables).

Answer (score -1):

Creating Azure storage using ARM template with some easy steps. Please find the following steps to implement it.

Step 1: Open your powershell and login your account with `Connect-AzureRmAccount`

step 2: add your SubscriptionId  `Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId <your SubscriptionId>`

step 3: Create Resource Group `New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name yourResourceGroup -Location "South Central US"`

Step 4: create azuredeploy.json and azuredeploy.parameters.json

**azuredeploy.json**

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the Azure Storage account."
        }
    },
    "containerName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "logs",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the blob container."
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The location in which the Azure Storage resources should be deployed."
        }
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS",
            "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "properties": {
            "accessTier": "Hot"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "[concat('default/', parameters('containerName'))]",
                "type": "blobServices/containers",
                "apiVersion": "2018-03-01-preview",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**azuredeploy.parameters.json**

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
        "value": "yourstorage"
    }
}
}
```

Step 5: run the following command

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name myDeployment -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroup -TemplateFile <location>\azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile <location>\azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

Step 6:

```
$saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroup -Name sitastoragee).Context 
New-AzureStorageTable –Name yourtablestorage –Context $saContext
```

Comment: This sample is to create a container instead of a table